# (ASP.NET) Project file must include 'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, build-process

I'm seeing an inscrutable compile error in my ASP.NET application.

> Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list

That's the WPF assembly.  My project is ASP.NET.  Has anyone ever encountered this before?

Even stranger, the project was compiling before I started messing around with my .resx files due to a different issue.  Then suddenly this nonsensical error appeared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens if you have a file in your project with its Build Action set to `Resource`. (which is used for WPF embedding)

Find the offending file and change its Build Action.

Comment: I did set the .resx files to Build Action = *Resource* while I was experimenting.  But currently nothing is set to that (confirmed by searching for "Resource" in the project file), and I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: Do you have anything other than `None`, `Compile`, or `Content`?

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks I think that's is.  I had set some of my .aspx files to "Page".  Changing them back to "Content" seems to have fixed the problem.  (That's what I get for monkeying around with stuff I don't understand.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the following in the csproj file:

```
<Page Include="BuildProcessTemplates\DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
<Page Include="BuildProcessTemplates\LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
<Page Include="BuildProcessTemplates\UpgradeTemplate.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
```

Changing it to below fixed the problem:

```
<Content Include="BuildProcessTemplates\DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml" />
<Content Include="BuildProcessTemplates\LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml" />
<Content Include="BuildProcessTemplates\UpgradeTemplate.xaml" />
```