# Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a solution worked ( Desktop WPF application ) , Suddenly I got this problem

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase,
> PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list.

I have tested all the solutions posted in StackOverflow but any of them worked for me and I have already these frameworks installed, I'm trying also to reinstall these frameworks but the problem persist.

[image]

[image: cr]

Comment: Try closing visual studio and deleting the `.vs` folder in your solution directory. You will lose some editor settings (layout etc.) so back it up in case deleting it doesn’t solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this solution doesn't fix my problem , the error still shown

Comment: Ah, worth a shot at least. Some more Googling may help; I just found this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820241/error-project-file-must-include-the-net-framework-assembly-windowsbase-prese), not sure if you’ve come across it already.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923189/asp-net-project-file-must-include-windowsbase-presentationcore-presentation

Comment: I have seen this question , but also does not seem to work for me

Comment: Worth checking the target version of your project matches the included the libraries. Also  mismatches between 32bit vs 64bit.

Comment: The error comes from the Crystal Report, I fixed the error by returning to the previous version ( I'm working with git source control )